# Join the related entity table if a condition met?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 2 tables, `ProductTypes` and `ProductTypesTranslations`. In ProductTypes I have

```
ID  Name
```

and in ProductTypesTranslations I have,

```
ID  ProductTypeID   LanguageID  Name
```

Now I need to grab the `ProductTypes.Name` if LanguageID 1, otherwise grab `ProductTypesTranslations.Name`. There is a 0 to 1 relation. I can do this,

```
declare @P nvarchar(100)
declare @LanguageID INT = 1
IF @LanguageID = 1 
    select @P = P.Name from ProductTypes P WHERE P.ID = 88
ELSE
    select @P = PT.Name from ProductTypes P INNER JOIN ProductTypesTranslations PT On P.ID = PT.ProductTypeID WHERE P.ID = 88
```

But I am thinking of a single SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
SELECT @P = CASE @LanguageID WHEN 0 THEN PT.Name ELSE P.Name END
FROM ProductTypes P 
LEFT JOIN ProductTypesTranslations PT On P.ID = PT.ProductTypeID 
                                         AND @LanguageID = 0 
WHERE P.ID = 88
```

The `INNER JOIN` becomes a `LEFT JOIN` that is "activated" only on `AND @LanguageID = 0`.

The selection of the field to be put in @P is made by a `CASE`.

When you change an `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN` you **must** be aware on the difference between the two. For example in this case an `INNER JOIN` on failure wouldn't have changed the value of `@P`, while the failure of the `LEFT JOIN` will put `NULL` in `@P`, but this isn't a problem because the value of `@P` before the `SELECT` is already `NULL`.